# Удаленное подключение к MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

Как удаленно подключиться к MongoDB только с определенного IP-адреса?

Если в настройках поменять bindIp c 127.0.0.1 на 0.0.0.0, то к базе можно будет коннектиться с любого адреса, а требуется доступ только через определенный айпишник.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38324964

Answer (score 0):

Ну вот возьми и замени 0.0.0.0 на нужный тебе ip адрес.

Можешь написать localhost, твойIP чтобы подключаться локально и с определенного ip.